# How to style Google maps info windows?

Tags: google-maps-api-3, styling

If you use the info windows in the iOS maps, they're sleek and small and aesthetically pleasing.

The google maps info windows, on the other hand, are huge white blocks with obnoxious shadows. Is there any way to style them-- to give them an *entirely* different appearance?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I *think* you're talking about InfoWindows, not info boxes (the distinction is important).

This is a Google Maps Version 3 InfoWindow:

[image: Google Maps image showing InfoWindow]

There is an [external utility library](http://code.google.com/p/google-maps-utility-library-v3/wiki/Libraries) called **InfoBox** which allows things like these:

[image: Google Maps image showing sample InfoBox] [image: Google Maps image showing sample InfoBox]

so it is possible to show different styles of information callout, and it's almost certainly possible to do something like iOS does (image from Macworld):

[image: Sample iOS map and info box]

Answer (score 2):

There is also a library called [InfoBubble](http://google-maps-utility-library-v3.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/infobubble/) that uses the same constructor as the InfoWindow but allows you to customise it. The [example page](http://google-maps-utility-library-v3.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/infobubble/examples/example.html) shows on that is styled like a iOS bubble.